# CKEditor flickers/resizes on page load before settling on correct size

Tags: ckeditor

hi there ive searched high and low to try find an answer to this one
would appreciate any help

see the screencast i took
http://screencast.com/t/B4y96D7rXgp

to explain the video
starts on the page with an editor in it 
i then hit refresh 
you can the editor loads like 100% height and then 100% width (from the editors left point) at first, then settles into its correct size
im hit refresh 3 times in the video to demo the bug
im using CKEditor 3.5.3 (revision 6655)

anyone got any ideas ive tried a few fixes like setting wifth and height etc but still does this stretch and contract thing

any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do. Probably not all of the required styling wasn't downloaded, so it wasn't applied. Try lessening the number of files you request and minifying your javascript/css. That's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of

> editor.on('instanceReady', function()
>       {
>        hide the container which has same height as ckeditor(you can probably
>   show loading here);
>        show the ckeditor container;
>       });