# Salesforce Rich text field to full mode feature

Tags: richtextbox

with the help of below link i have implemented

[How to convert Salesforce rich text editor to a "full mode" editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228900/how-to-convert-salesforce-rich-text-editor-to-a-full-mode-editor/9233618#9233618)

But Having an issue ,either i am in dev mode or not the page is keep on refreshing and the rich text is flickering.

Any idea why it is happening

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor flickers/resizes on page load before settling on correct size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900384/ckeditor-flickers-resizes-on-page-load-before-settling-on-correct-size)

Comment: CKEDITOR.replace(name, {
                        height : 500, 
                        bodyId : target
            });

Comment: If i adjust  the height parameter will it work ?